# trying to understand the execution sequence in some js codes

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var DYN_WEB = DYN_WEB || {};
DYN_WEB.Util = (function( Ut ) {
    Ut.getResult = function ( cl, tag, el ) {
    console.log(arguments)
    }
return Ut;
})( DYN_WEB.Util || {} );
var links = DYN_WEB.Util.getResult('show-hide');
</script>
```

In chrome->console, it shows: `["show-hide"]`

Question:

when script goes to this line:`DYN_WEB.Util`, did not reach `var links` yet, why `console.log(arguments)` can still outputs `["show-hide"]` , not `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some extra lines if you want to understand the execution flow. The `getResult` function is called on the `links` line. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q4N6N/):

```
var DYN_WEB = DYN_WEB || {};
DYN_WEB.Util = (function (Ut) {
    Ut.getResult = function (cl, tag, el) {
        console.log(arguments)
    }
    return Ut;
})(DYN_WEB.Util || {});
console.log("before links");
var links = DYN_WEB.Util.getResult('show-hide');
console.log("after links");
```

The console output will be:

```
before links
["show-hide"]
after links
```

Answer (score 0):

`DYN_WEB.Util` is a function and will not execute itself.
So you are wrong at the point that it not reach at the var links.

First it will reach at the `var links` from where it will call to `DYN_WEB.Util` function and it will pass the arguments that you are using.

So the flow of calling will be first it call to `var links` from where it call to `DYN_WEB.Util` function that it initialize above and then execute the `console.log`.

And it output the show-hide.